# How to rewrite a container base class in symfony 3.2

Tags: symfony

I use symfony `3.2`. I want to rewrite `app/AppKernel#getContainerBaseClass`. Actuallly I want to rewrite `Container` and create my own which extends from `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container`.

I found that `AppKernel` has `#getContainerBaseClass` which as I understood returns container class. I tried the following:

```
protected function getContainerBaseClass() {
    if ('test' == $this->environment) {
        return \AppBundle\DependencyInjection\TestContainer::class;
    }

    return parent::getContainerBaseClass();
}
```

And it does not work. How I know that it does not work. Firstly I check that the container does not behaviour from customized container. Second I set breakpoint inside mentioned method and it was not called. But breakpoints in `AppKernel#getRootDir` and `AppKernel#getCacheDir` were called. I searched in `Kernel` for something useful. But it was difficult to understand why it did not work. I tried to clear the cache.

It seems to me that I do something wrong. But internet have just nothing about rewriting symfony container. It is strange.

I want to rewrite the container to allow changing (mocking) configuration. Currently as I know symfony has fridged parameter bag which can not be changed.

Comment: Out of curiousity: What's the need to rewrite the container?

Comment: @ccKep updates the Q

Comment: The relevant methods should be `getContainerClass` (not only `getContainerBaseClass`) and `initializeContainer` in the base `Kernel` class. [Lines 452 - 501 in Kernel.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php) for reference.

Comment: Generally do not understand why they are relevant. `getContainerClass` is class which works in cache. Consider `$class = $this->getContainerClass();
        $cache = new ConfigCache($this->getCacheDir().'/'.$class.'.php', $this->debug);`. In `initializeContainer` I can only basically decorate container but it is limited.

Comment: The Kernel calls `initializeContainer()` in `boot()`, which in turn gets the container class name from `getContainerClass()`, not `getContainerBaseClass()`. After that, it's `$this->container = new $class();`

Comment: @ccKep But what about `!$cache->isFresh()`. Does it mean that if cache is clear? But I got that I should rewrite `initializeContainer`. For this I have to copy all that inner stuff and add condition to `!$cache->isFresh()` so that my class would be used.

Comment: That part just dumps the container into the cache directory, it doesn't stop the `$this->container = new $class();` part. You shouldn't need to rewrite the `initializeContainer` method, just return your own container class namespace+name in `getContainerClass` (and probably `getContainerBaseClass` ?) so your's gets instantiated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168067/discussion-between-freelightman-and-cckep).

Answer (score 0):

So to understand how answer works and if it fits you - few comments.

There is two classes which are relevant to container. First, container itself: `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container`. It is not changed for each env and it contains dynamic methods which have no actual data (no params, services, just calls to get it).  Second, bundled container. And it contains all parameters and services. It parsed yml files and make methods / properties from them. It contains much more methods than `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container`. For example it has `#getDefaultParameters` which returns all parameters in one array. It also has `#getTwigService` which actually makes twig instance. So it turns yml files in php props and methods. This bundles container class name and namespace depends on env. So for test env it is `\appTestDebugProjectContainer`. And as it is compiled and varies from env, it is located in cache folder. And last thing: it is extended from `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container`.

In addition compiled container has some dynamic methods which overwrite `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container` (for example `#getParameter`).

So now we can back to the question. `AppKernel` has the following methods relevant to the container:

- `getContainerBaseClass` which returns source container. By default it is `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container`. You can change it so that it returns your customized container. But actually there is not so much that you can customize because bundles container rewrites a lot of methods and adds own logic.
- `getContainerClass` which returns bundles container class name. Here is the point. It is the container which is actually used in your env. And you can extend it. But first you should know from which class to extend. For my test env it is `appTestDebugProjectContainer`. You may get class for your need from the following logic:

  return $this->name.ucfirst($this->environment).($this->debug ? 'Debug' : '').'ProjectContainer';

`$this->name` is usually `app`. Other things is pretty straightforward.
 - `initializeContainer` it does all things getting and booting a container. The line in which we are interested is `$this->container = new $class();`. We should rewrite `$class` var with our

So what is the end solution. Create you own container somewhere and extend it from bundled container name. Rewrite `#initializeContainer` in AppKernel.

The example for test env continer is.

1. Create the container:

```

namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

class TestContainer extends \appTestDebugProjectContainer {

```
public $fakeParams = [];

public function getParameter($name) {
    $fake = @$this->fakeParams[$name];
    if ($fake) return $fake;
    return parent::getParameter($name);
}
```

}

```

2. Rewrite `#getContainerClass` in AppKernel:

```
    class AppKernel extends Kernel
    {
    // ...
    protected function initializeContainer()
    {
        $class = $this->getContainerClass();
        $cache = new ConfigCache($this->getCacheDir().'/'.$class.'.php', $this->debug);
        $fresh = true;

```
    if (!$cache->isFresh()) {
        $container = $this->buildContainer();
        $container->compile();
        $this->dumpContainer($cache, $container, $class, $this->getContainerBaseClass());

        $fresh = false;
    }

    require_once $cache->getPath();
    if ('test' == $this->environment) {
        $class = \AppBundle\DependencyInjection\TestContainer::class;
    }


    $this->container = new $class();
    $this->container->set('kernel', $this);

    if (!$fresh && $this->container->has('cache_warmer')) {
        $this->container->get('cache_warmer')->warmUp($this->container->getParameter('kernel.cache_dir'));
    }
}
}
```

```

I inserted only the following lines:

```
if ('test' == $this->environment) {
            $class = \AppBundle\DependencyInjection\TestContainer::class;
        }
```

Everything else is just copied from `Kernel#initializeContainer`.

That works for me.

To see what you can extend you can inspect bundled container which is located (for test env) in `var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php`.